# How to write a file to a folder in Desktop using write_file in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, backup, directory

I am using this code for write file in CodeIgniter.

```
$backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);

write_file("application/backup/backup.sql.gz", $backup);
```

But I need to write that specified file *backup.sql.gz* to another folder in desktop.
How it is possible using this write_file() in codeigniter.

Comment: desktop means client machine desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the path on write_file function

```
$backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);

write_file("/home/my_pc/Desktop/NewFolder/backup.sql.gz", $backup);
```

Give permission to NewFolder. It will work.